# Latex subfigure arrangement

Tags: floats, subfloats

I need help with arranging subfigures in this manner (as subfigure b is a different height but same width as a and c)
Any help much appreciated!

[image]

edit: I've been using the `subcaption` package!

Comment: Please tell us whether you employ the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package.

Comment: The image is missing (for me anyway).

Comment: fixed! (it went away somehow when i edited i think)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that employs the `subcaption` package and its `subfigure` environment.

Inside the `figure` environment, there are two side by side `minipage` environments, each with width `0.45\textwidth`, separated horizontally by `\hfill`. The left-hand `minipage` environment contains 2 `subfigure` environments, numbered "(a)" and "(c)"; the right-hand `minipage` environment contains just 1 `subfigure` environment, numbered "(b)". The widths of the 3 `subfigure` environments are set to `\linewidth`.

With this setup, you can create cross-references to both the overall figure and to the subfigures via the usual `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove `demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} % start of first minipage
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picA}
\caption{\dots}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip % leave empty line before '\bigskip'
\addtocounter{subfigure}{1} % increment 'subfigure' counter by 1
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picC}
\caption{\dots}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage} % end of first minipage
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} % start of second minipage
\addtocounter{subfigure}{-2} % decrement 'subfigure' counter by 2
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth]{picB}
\caption{\dots}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage} % end of second minipage

\caption{Overall figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The spacing in your code is a bit confusing, e.g. the first block containing \begin{figure} to \end{subfigure}. I assumed when I saw this that I could space out the code however I wanted, so I added spaces between the minipage environments which lead to this solution not working. Only when I removed the blank lines between the minipage environments did it work. Just saying this to help avoid the problem I encountered. But in the end it did work, so you get my upvote.

Comment: @arara - I'm afraid I really don't follow you. For instance, you write that "[o]nly when I removed the blank lines between the minipage environments did it work." Sorry, but there simply are no blank lines between the two `minipage` environments in my code. What are you referring to? Please clarify.

Comment: I understand that, and your code is fine as is, although the spacing you chose made me assume that it was generally fine to space the code for myself how I liked. So when I was reproducing it, I aesthetically added blank lines between \end{minipage} and the next \begin{minipage}. But this introduced an issue which I then had to figure out by eliminating blank lines. I personally think this incorrect assumption can be omitted if you deleted the blank line you have between \end{subfigure} and \bigskip.

Comment: @arara - Actually, the presence of the blank line between the first instance of `\end{subfigure}` and  `\bigskip` is entirely justified, and I certainly put the blank line there *deliberately*, because a (paragraph) break is very much needed at that location. In contrast, no paragraph break is desirable between the two `minipage` environments, and that's why I -- equally deliberately! -- did *not* insert one or more blank lines either before or  after `\hfill` ("horizontal fill"). Moral of the story: only leave one or more blank lines where you are ok with line and paragraph breaks occurring.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the clarification

Comment: This was perfect! I also adjusted it for different arrangements, and thank you for introducing `\addtocounter` to me!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest approach is to typeset the subfloats first, saving them in boxes that can be moved around later as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\subcapboxA}
\newsavebox{\subcapboxB}
\newsavebox{\subcapboxC}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\sbox{\subcapboxA}{%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
}
\sbox{\subcapboxB}{%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
}
\sbox{\subcapboxC}{%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
}

% Now we stack the boxes in the desired way
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \usebox{\subcapboxA} \\[2ex]
  \usebox{\subcapboxC}
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \usebox{\subcapboxB}
\end{tabular}

\caption{The global caption text}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some document classes don't support usage of the `caption` package (`revtex4-2` and others), so you need to use `subfig`. Here's the corresponding code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\subcapboxA}
\newsavebox{\subcapboxB}
\newsavebox{\subcapboxC}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\sbox{\subcapboxA}{%
  \subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  }%
}
\sbox{\subcapboxB}{%
  \subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
  }%
}
\sbox{\subcapboxC}{%
  \subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-c}%
  }%
}

% Now we stack the boxes in the desired way
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \usebox{\subcapboxA} \\[2ex]
  \usebox{\subcapboxC}
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \usebox{\subcapboxB}
\end{tabular}

\caption{The global caption text}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]\\
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \caption{Table with 3 graphs}
            \begin{tabular}{l l}
                \parbox{2in}{\includegraphics[width=2in,height=1in]{seno.pdf}\\ (a)  sinus graph\\ \includegraphics[width=2in,height=1in]{coseno.pdf}\\(b)  cosinus graph} &\parbox{2in}{\includegraphics[width=2in,height=2.2in]{tangente.pdf}\\ (c)   tangent graph}\\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: An issue I have with this is that it's supposed to be a figure but has a Table caption. To get around that I guess you'd have to do a caption*{ } instead of caption{ } and manually begin the caption with the text "Figure 1:". But this is still problematic, because it messes with the automatic numbering of other tables and figures. You'd need to add additional commands to change the figure and table counter. This is a cool idea but I think this mixing of the figure / table boundaries can be an issue.

Comment: @arara - An even simpler solution: Use a `figure` environment instead of a `table` environment.